# Select range of sheets in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to select a range of worksheets in an Excel macro, so that they can then be printed.

I want to print a range, i.e. Sheet2-Sheetx, where x is a variable.

I have tried recording a macro to do what I want, but it uses sheet names rather than sheet references, and of course doesn't support variables.

In this example, I selected three sheets, so x=3:

```
Sheets(Array("Data", "Data (2)", "Data (3)")).Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut preview:=True
```

I would have thought this would be simple, but can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Name` is the property that you need to get the 
Worksheet's names like this:

```
WorkSheets(Array(Worksheets(1).Name, Worksheets(2).Name, Worksheets(3).Name)).Select
```

And if you want to do it fancy, with `N` as a variable, try like this:

```
Public Sub SelectN()

    Dim N           As Long: N = 2
    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim arrOfWs     As Variant

    ReDim arrOfWs(N - 1)
    For cnt = 1 To N
        arrOfWs(cnt - 1) = Worksheets(cnt).Name
    Next cnt
    Worksheets(arrOfWs).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent; just what I was after. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me, I would however make it shorter:

```
Sheets(Array("Data", "Data (2)", "Data (3)")).Printout Preview: = -1
```

Check sheets' names spelling.