# Selecting a range of worksheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a print macro in VBA that will print to a pdf all worksheets between and including a worksheet named "Beginning" and a worksheet named "End".  I don't want to use all the sheet names as I want the code to work if a new worksheet is inserted between "Beginning" and "End".  I basically just need the code that selects the worksheets.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I have had no luck.  I tried searching the web and stack overflow but can't find any code that selects a range of worksheets where you just specify the beginning name and ending name.  Plenty of code for selecting all worksheets and for selecting a range where you specify all the names, but not for what I need.

Comment: `For i = Worksheets("Beginning").Index to Worksheets("End").Index`

Comment: Maybe [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639776/select-range-of-sheets-in-excel-vba) will help.

Comment: Miles - I had seen that but not quite what I was looking for.  Scott - thanks very much.  That is very useful.  Now I need to loop through the sheets, select them all, and print, but I should be able to figure the rest out.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again, Scott.  Below is the full solution.  Also had to check if the worksheet was hidden which caused an error:

Sub print_all()
    For i = Worksheets("Beggining").Index To Worksheets("End").Index
        If Worksheets(i).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then Else Worksheets(i).Select False
    Next i
    
    
   ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below;

```
Sub SaveBeginningToEnd()
    Dim wsBeginning As Worksheet
    Dim wsEnd As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsBeginning = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Beginning")
    Set wsEnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("End")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wsBeginning Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Cannot find worksheet Beginning"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf wsEnd Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Cannot find worksheet End"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf wsBeginning.Index > wsEnd.Index Then
        Debug.Print "Beginning Worksheet is after End Worksheet."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim varSheets() As Long
    ReDim varSheets(wsEnd.Index - wsBeginning.Index)

    For i = wsBeginning.Index To wsEnd.Index
        varSheets(i - wsBeginning.Index) = i
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(varSheets).Select

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fd.Title = "Save As PDF"
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    For intIndex = 1 To fd.Filters.Count
        If fd.Filters(intIndex).Description = "PDF" Then fd.FilterIndex = intIndex
    Next
    If fd.Show = -1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, fd.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a ton T4roy.  Very robust code.  Will definitely use it.